# Why won't the VScode ChromeDriver display the website url I am trying to open?

Tags: beautifulsoup, selenium-chromedriver

I am working on a scraping project and have all recent downloads of python (3.9.5), VScode, Selenium, and BeautifulSoup. All the modules seem to be working correctly and I receive no errors when running the code. However, the URL is not opened by the web driver when I run the code - nothing happens? Please assist me in what I am missing so I am able to see my control window/display.

Code:

```py
import csv
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium import webdriver

# Startup the webdriver

driver = webdriver.Chrome()

url = 'https://www.amazon.com'
driver.get(url)
```

Output:

```sh
[Running] python -u "/Library/Frameworks/Python. framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/
ScrapingTest.py"
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/bs4/element.py:16:
UserWarning: The soupsieve package is not installed. csS selectors cannot be used.
'The soupsieve package is not installed. CSS selectors cannot be used.'
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/ScrapingTest.py",
line 2, in <module>
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/bs4/_init_-py",
line 32, in <module>
from .builder import builder_registry, ParserRejectedMarkup
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/bs4/builder/
_init_.py", line 7, in <module>
from bs4.element import (
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/bs4/element.py",
line 19, in <module>
from bs4. formatter import (
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/bs4/formatter.py",
line 1, in <module>
from bs4.dammit import EntitySubstitution
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/bs4/dammit.py",
line 68, in <module>
class EntitySubstitution(object):
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/bs4/dammit.py",
line 97, in EntitySubstitution
CHARACTER_TO_HTML_ENTITY_RE) = _populate_class_variables ()
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python. framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/bs4/dammit.py",
line 83, in _populate_class_variables
character = chr(codepoint)
ValueError: chr() arg not in range (256)
[Done] exited with code=1 in 0.198 seconds
```

Comment: Please read, and interpret, the error/warning.... (which you should have added as text in this question, and not in a picture...)

Comment: There is the chr() not in range error - but regardless a command window should open the url in chrome.

Comment: I was referring to the waring "CSS selector cannot be used" because some package is not installed.

Answer (score 0):

The error message states that:

> UserWarning: The soupsieve package is not installed. css selectors cannot be used.

Hence, installing the `soupsieve` package using `pip install soupsieve` should fix the error.